# pgfgantt: There is no , in font nullfont!

Tags: pgfgantt, silence

I'm aware that this question has been asked many times here in different variations. However, I couldn't find a question regarding this topic that was related to *pgfgantt*. Nor could I find this topic where a comma "," was missing.

Using the option `vgrid={draw=none, dotted}` causes a warning for me at the top of the section (or document, if no section is provided) with the following text:

```
Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!
```

I managed to replicate this warning from my own text (not shown here) with a minimal example taken directly from the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt), page 11.

```
\documentclass{article}
 
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
 
\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid={draw=none, dotted}]{1}{12}
    \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
    \ganttbar{}{1}{4} \\
    \ganttbar{}{5}{11}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

The chart is displayed correctly and I do not understand why the warning is there or how I can get rid of it.

The warning persists if we reduce the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
 
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
 
\begin{document}
 
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid={draw=none, dotted}]{1}{1}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

I get these warnings in VSC with MiKTeX, <s>but I can't reproduce them in Overleaf (where these examples give no errors or warnings, and work as intended).</s> Edit: Overleaf doesn't put it as a warning, but the text `Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!` exists in the log.

Updated example (code is correct according to manual but warning persists):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningsOff*

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid={*1{draw=none}, *1{dotted}}]{1}{12}
    \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
    \ganttbar{}{1}{4} \\
    \ganttbar{}{5}{11}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

This creates the following, wanted, figure, where there are vertical dotted lines on every other column:

[image]

I know now that the warning is harmless but I would like to get rid of it regardless. It may not be possible to type this correctly for pgfgantt, but we should be able to silence the warning. However, using the package `silence`, with all warnings turned off using `\WarningsOff*`, I'm still receiving this warning. How do we make it go away?

Comment: Are you sure that these warnings don't occur on overleaf? Overleaf won't show them to you, but they should still be in the .log file.

Comment: For some reason, a comma used in the internals isn't gobbled and it generates the warning. It's innocuous.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Ok yes. I checked the log and you're correct: the line "Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!" exists in the log.

Answer (score 5):

Imho the documentation forgot to follow its own advice. On the page before it explicitly says

> However, if you wish to use a single style comprising two or more keys for all grid
> lines, e. g. red, dotted, you must retain the multiplier (i. e., `{*1{red, dotted}}`).

and show a "wrong" and "correct" example

[image]

And if one follows this advice and adds the multiplier the missing char warning disappears:

```
\documentclass{article}
 
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid=*1{draw=none, dotted}]{1}{12}
    \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
    \ganttbar{}{1}{4} \\
    \ganttbar{}{5}{11}
\end{ganttchart}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting. This does indeed remove the warning. But it also removes all the vertical dotted lines (which I guess is reasonable considering the keyword draw=none). But it wasn't what I expected when following the manual.

Comment: well draw=none should certainly not draw something neither notted nor undotted, and it previously only "worked" imho because of the parsing error.

Comment: This follows the logic better: vgrid = {*1{draw=none}, *1{dotted}}. Now the vgrid alternates between blank and alternating (like it did from the start), with the same syntax as on page 9. Still have the warning though.